# C++ server, Java InputStreamReader.read cant return -1 and BufferedReader not return value

Tags: java, c++, sockets

Developing a C++ Server with Java platform. Stack with some little problem. Hope anyone can help here

C++ Server code fragment

```
// Sample send a socket
sned(ConnectedSocket, classroomlist, strlen(classromlist), 0);
```

In Java Client

```
// Catch the socket
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

char[] buffer = new char[3];
```

And the problem come here

1. If I use BufferedReader, Nothing read out.
2. And I try to use

   while((x = inr.read(buffer)) != -1){}

, stack into the while loop while reading. ( Discover why no output for BufferedReader )

1. And I try to `while(true){ SYstem.out.println(inr.read(buffer)) }` 
   print out all the length of each round of reading.
   Problem found! 
   Output Like this
   vvvvvvvvvvv

   05-31 11:35:09.934: D/@@@(3264): 3
   05-31 11:35:09.934: D/@@@(3264): 3
   05-31 11:35:09.934: D/@@@(3264): 3
   05-31 11:35:09.934: D/@@@(3264): 2

`InputStremaReader.read()` suppose `return -1` if the tcp package reach the end.
But the function just stack beforn the end and waiting waiting waitinggggggg.

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: Want to get the response text in Java client :D The problem with 'But the function just stack beforn the end and waiting waiting waitinggggggg.'

Comment: If you are using a socket won't it only return -1 when the connection is _closed_ and 0 if no data was read? Does the socket block on the read?

Comment: This is a continuation of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16848880/1667977
You need to simply close the socket as you were already told.

Comment: But in Java to Java Socket programming, socket dont need to close to finish the package sent. You can use socket.getInputStream() and socket.getOutputStream() many time

Comment: Dont work too if I add closesocket(ConnectedSocket);

Answer (score 1):

If the sender never closes the socket, the receiver will never get the end-of-stream condition.

Conversely, if the receiver never gets the end-of-stream condition, the conclusion must be that the sender never closes the socket.

Comment: but a socket connect can have many data package send??? I found that using datainputstream can solve the problem